# Passing arguments in tcl procedure of ns2

Tags: tcl

Below is my simple procedure in tcl

```
set mymin 8

proc ann { mymin } { 
    puts stdout "$mymin is the answer"
}
ann
```

When i run this it keeps giving error as:

wrong # args: should be "ann mymin"

Please let me know what is the issue here. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call `ann` with an argument because that's how you wrote your proc.

```
ann $mymin
```